# Swift get value data from protocol

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

i need help with my code for swift 5,

so i make a struct and protocol to store list from uitextfield and now i wanna show that data in a UiTextView in another view controller

```
struct PatientNote {

var note : String

init(note :String) {
    self.note = note
  }
}  

protocol AddNotesDelegate {

    func AddNotes(controller : UIViewController, notes: PatientNote)
}

class AddNotesController: UIViewController {

var delegate : AddNotesDelegate!

@IBOutlet weak var Notes: UITextView!

@IBAction func addNotes(_ sender: Any) {

    if let notes = self.Notes.text {

        let patientNote = PatientNote(note: notes)
        self.delegate.AddNotes(controller: self, notes: patientNote)
        print(patientNote.note)

    }
  }
}
```

and now i wanna show in my view controller but i get this error of "Cannot convert value of type 'PatientNote' to expected argument type 'String'" in this viewController

```
class NotePatientController: UIViewController, AddNotesDelegate{

func AddNotes(controller: UIViewController, notes: PatientNote) {

    let NotesPatient = PatientNote(note: notes) *this is where i get the error

}

var delegate : AddNotesDelegate!

var pasien : PatientNote!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    PatientTextView.text = pasien.note

}

@IBOutlet weak var PatientTextView: UITextView!


//in this ibaction i edit the notes that i get from the first Vc which is AddNotesController
@IBAction func Save(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if let notes = self.PatientTextView.text {
        let pasienNotes = PatientNote(note: notes)

        self.delegate.AddNotes(controller: self, notes: pasienNotes)
    } 
  }
}
```

i try to show the note from the AddNotesController to the NotePatientController, and in the NotePatientController i can edit and save the notes in UiTextView.

so i know i must be using the protocol in a wrong way, can someone help me how should i use it? im still kinda new in swift so could probably use any help i can get, Cheer!

Comment: From what I see, on the line where you're getting the error you're passing an already initialised `PatientNote` object to the initialiser for `PatientNote` which requires a `String`. I'm not sure to what extent this would fix the problems but could the `let notesPatient` statement be omitted completely? And in that case if you need to access the notes String in the AddNotes function you can use `notes.note` instead.

Comment: i try that and it works, but now i have to figure out how to show it in the uitextview cause the textview just blank

Answer (score 1):

Change `let notesPatient = PatientNote(note: notes)` to `let notesPatient = PatientNote(note: notes.note)`

Comment: Thanks for the commend it really worked, but now i cant show the notes into the uitextview, the uitextview just blank

Answer (score 0):

It appears PatientNote takes a `String` as an argument but you passed an already created PatientNote to it instead. The below syntax, using `notes.note` would be a cleaner solution without involving initialising a new PatientNote.

```
func AddNotes(controller: UIViewController, notes: PatientNote) {

    print(notes.note) // access the note String like this

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it works to, but why the uitextview is blank, i put this line "self.PatientTextView.text = notes.note" inside the func

Comment: @afipermana has the delegate been set correctly? Maybe try using a print function to make sure the AddNotes() is called in the first place if you haven’t already done so. Your code for setting the text is otherwise correct so I think the delegate might be the problem.